When do you know you're "done" cleaning a very dirty grill (was not used for about 7 months)
How do I know my grill is clean enough to use? I scrubbed the parts food touch with a dish soap and baking powder solution and rinsed the heat guards off well. There is some rust on these, not too much. What else should I check before I know it's safe for food? (it's a propane grill)

Rinse all the soap, baking soda, etcetera residue off.
Light it. Close the lid. (Empty grill, no food, just grates and high flame.)
If it has a thermometer, let it get to 350°F / 175°C or more. If not, give it 20 minutes or so of heating.
Anything left at that point is a cosmetic issue at most, not a food safety issue, unless you've been processing something other than food in the grill previously.
If you'd like the grates cleaner, clean them more - or as many people do, use a secondary grate on the grill's grate rather than putting food directly on the grill's grate if you can't clean it to your satisfaction. But it should be entirely safe after thorough heating, including any burned on stubborn material. Heating may make any stuck material come off more easily, as well.

One thing to be extremely cautious of when cleaning a grill is wires coming off a wire brush -- use a nylon brush or a ball of aluminium foil.

source: https://x.com/USCPSC/status/1520139268227833856
